# Numbers 3358 & 2583, 3 replaced by 8, and 8 replaced by 3 In Python

Tags: python-3.x

There are two numbers

```
3358
2583
```

3 can be replaced by 8 and 8 can be replaced by 3.

List out all combinations of interchangeable numbers and display maximum, minimum and average of the numbers
Please share solution using Python..

Answer (score 0):

```
number = '3358'
l_number = list(number)

numbers = set()

def rec_interchange(index):
    global l_number, numbers
    if index == len(l_number):
        return
    for i in range(index, len(l_number)):
        if l_number[i] == '3':
            l_number[i] = '8'
            numbers.add(''.join(l_number))
            rec_interchange(i + 1)
        if l_number[i] == '8':
            l_number[i] = '3'
            numbers.add(''.join(l_number))
            rec_interchange(i + 1)

rec_interchange(0)

numbers = [int(num) for num in numbers]
print(numbers)

print(f'Max: {max(numbers)}  Min: {min(numbers)}  Avg: {sum(numbers) / len(numbers)}')
```

Result for 3358 is: `Max: 8858  Min: 3353  Avg: 6105.5`